# Android Print Manager - return saved pdf file path

Tags: java, android

Using Android [PrintManager API](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html) user can save content as PDF into device's internal/external directory.

I need to get that PDF file's path as soon as it is created. Is there any way to do this directly without having to use a file chooser?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using Android PrintManager API we can save content as PDF into device's internal/external directory.

No. The *user* can elect to send your print job to a PDF file that is stored locally. The user could elect to do something else:

- Send it to an actual printer
- Send it to something else (e.g., Cloud Print)
- Abandon the print job

> Is there any way to do this directly without having to use a file chooser?

No, simply because there is no requirement for the user to save the content to a local PDF file in a place that you can access. In addition to all the above non-PDF alternatives, the user could save it as a PDF to removable storage, in a directory that your app cannot access.

> I need to get that PDF file's path as soon as it is created

Then the `PrintManager` API is not suitable. Generate a PDF some other way (e.g., iText).